# Изменить адрес админ панели htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

Доброго времени суток.
Помогите разобраться в коде htaccess

```
# Hide admin URL start
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my_admin_url/?$ /wp-login.php?my_secret_key [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^my_admin_url/?$ /wp-login.php?my_secret_key&redirect_to=/wp-admin/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^my_admin_url/?$ /wp-admin/?my_secret_key [R,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.com/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.com/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.com/my_admin_url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^my_secret_key
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=postpass
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^loggedout=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wp-login.php?my_secret_key [R,L]
</IfModule>
# Hide admin URL end
```

> my_admin_url – замените название, на желаемое. По этому адресу будет доступен ваш сайт.
>   my_secret_key – вместо данной строки придумайте сложный ключ и запишите его.
>   site.com – замените на домен вашего сайта.
>
> Также, если вы воспользовались предыдущей статьей о замене страницы wp-login.php (стандартная страница входа), измените строки в коде.
>
> Например: Ваша страница называется admin-login.php, замените 5 значений wp-login в коде на admin-login.

Суть в том, что если я заменяю все как написано в инструкции, то сайт по моему новому адресу админки - выдает ошибку.

Потом оставил это строчку как написано в инструкции, т.е. без изменений и всё заработало.

```
RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]
```

Теперь не понимаю как "скрыть" мой секретный ключ! Если перехожу напрямую в админку по ссылке site.com/my_admin_url то он и мой ключ сразу отображает в браузерной строке, т.е. site.com/my_admin_url.php?my_secret_key

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я сделал неверно?!

И вообще, не нашел описания, для чего это ключ нужен...

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать плагин  Lockdown WP Admin

Comment: @Plikard, спасибо. Приму к сведению!